# Finding the sparsest solution to a system of linear equations

Tags: np-hardness, linear-algebra, linear-programming, matrices, sparse-matrix

How hard is it to find the sparsest solution to a system of linear equations?

More formally, consider the following decision problem:

**Instance:** A system of linear equations with integer coefficients and a number $c$.

**Question:** Does there exist a solution to the system with at least $c$ variables assigned to zero?

I'm also trying to determine what the dependence is on $c$.  That is, maybe the problem is FPT with parameter $c$.

Any ideas or references are really appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

Consider the problem $\text{MAX-LIN}(R)$ of maximizing the number of satisfied linear equations over some ring $R$, which is often NP-hard, for example in the case $R=\mathbb{Z}$

Take an instance of this problem, $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a $n\times m$ matrix. Let $k=m+1$. Construct a new linear system $\tilde{A}\tilde{x} = \tilde{b}$, where $\tilde{A}$ is a $kn \times (kn+m)$ matrix, $\tilde{x}$ is now a $(kn+m)$ dimensional vector, and $\tilde{b}$ is a $kn$ dimensional vector:

$$\tilde{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
 A & I_n & &  & \\
 & I_n & -I_n & & \\
 & & I_n & -I_n & \\
 & & & \ddots &\ddots  \\
 & & & & I_n & -I_n \\
\end{bmatrix}, \tilde{b} = \begin{bmatrix} b \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
where $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Note that this system is always satisfied by the vector $\tilde{x} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & b & b & \cdots &  b \end{pmatrix}^T$. In fact, the first $m$ entries of $\tilde{x}$ can be arbitrary, and there is some solution vector with that prefix.

I now claim that $\delta$ fraction of equations of $Ax=b$ are satisfiable iff there exists a sparse solution of $\tilde{A}\tilde{x}=\tilde{b}$ which has at least $\delta nk$ zeros. This is because every satisfied row of $Ax=b$ yields $k$ potential zeros when $x$ is extended to $\tilde{x}$

Thus, if we find the sparsity of the sparsest solution to $\tilde{A}\tilde{x}=\tilde{b}$, we have also maximized $\delta$, by dividing the sparsity by $k$.

Therefore, I believe your problem is NP-hard.

Comment: Cool!  Thank you for sharing.  So what do you think the dependence is on c?  Do you think we can solve it in less than $poly(n) \cdot {n \choose c}$ where $n$ is the input size?

Comment: Sure: if we assume you're given which $c$ elements of $x$ are zero, then you can simply remove those elements from $x$ to get a lower dimensional $x'$ and also remove the corresponding columns from $A$ to get $A'$. Then use gaussian elimination to decide if the reduced system $A' x' = b$ is feasible; if it is, then you've found a sparse solution. Then, you try all $\binom{n}{c}$ possible $A'x'$.

Comment: @MichaelWehar I don't know whether this problem is FPT or not though

Answer (score 6):

The problem is NP-complete, by reduction from the following problem: 
Given an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with integer entries and an integer vector $b$ with $n$ entries, does there exist a 0-1 vector $x$ with $Ax=b$?

For every coordinate $x_i$ of vector $x$,

- introduce $100(n+m)$ new equations $x_i+y_{i,k}=0$ with $k=1,\ldots,100(n+m)$, and
- introduce $100(n+m)$ new equations $x_i+z_{i,k}=1$ with $k=1,\ldots,100(n+m)$.

Furthermore use the old equation system $Ax=b$.

There exists a 0-1 solution to the original system $Ax=b$, if and only if the new system has a solution in which at least $100(n+m)n$ variables are zero.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is *hard*, in various settings. As stated in the other answers to this question, the problem is NP-complete over the integers.

In signal processing, the matrix and the vectors have rational entries, and this problem is sometimes called the *sparse reconstruction problem*. In this setting, the problem is [NP-complete](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0097539792240406) (see Theorem 1).

In coding theory, the entries are from a finite field, and this problem is sometimes called the *maximum-likelihood decoding* problem. In this setting, the problem is [NP-complete](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIT.1978.1055873) and [not in subexponential time](http://conference.itcs.tsinghua.edu.cn/ICS2011/content/paper/33.pdf), assuming the exponential time hypothesis. Furthermore, according to a previous version of [a paper on arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3054v1) (see Lemma C.2 in version 1 of the paper), the problem is W[1]-complete.

Comment: Your reference for W[1]-completeness does not appear to have a "Lemma C.2". ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer There is a Lemma C.2 in version 1 of the paper that he linked.  However, version 2 seems to have a different title and was very recently changed.

Comment: That lemma uses a different parameterization from the OP. ​ ​

Comment: Oh I didn't realize there was an updated version, I'll take a look at it and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, that "lemma uses a different parameterization from the OP", so even if we assume the result is true (despite having been removed from version 2), the OP's question about parameterized complexity would still be open. ​ ​

Comment: Well, the parameter in the linked paper is *k*, which corresponds to the number of *nonzero* entries in a solution vector (in their equivalent setting, it is the cardinality of a subset of vectors); this number wants to be minimized. The original problem asked about *c*, the number of *zero* entries in a solution vector; this number wants to be maximized. So they are equivalent if we consider *c* to be *n* - *k*.

Comment: Even then, they're not equivalent - the linked paper is considering solutions with at most a small number of non-zero entries, the original problem is considering solutions with at least a small number of zero entries, and parameterized complexity focuses on cases in which the parameter is small. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 4):

This is called the Sparsest Solution Vector problem, and [it is indeed NP-hard](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~donoho/Reports/2005/NonNegative-R5.pdf).